# Why does React warn "Unknown prop `p` on <p> tag. Remove this prop from the element." when there's no such prop?

Tags: reactjs

I get warnings like this when upgrading from React 0.13.3 to 15.4.2:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `p` on <p> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see https://fb.me/ react-unknown-prop
    in p (created by Unknown)
```

(I had to split up the URL to get around a "no URL shorteners" thing on Stack Overflow; don't want to expand it because that would make the quoted error message inaccurate.)

But I don't see any use of such a property. What could be the issue?

Comment: Normally it'd make sense to include the code that generates the error, otherwise I'm not sure how anybody could actually help.

Comment: @DaveNewton I posted the answer along with the question – so people who search for this error message (like I did) can find my solution below. Before I solved the issue, I didn't know what code specifically caused it (that was part of the mystery…), but the answer includes that code.

Comment: Understood. It's just a warning that in general a question with an error and no code is essentially impossible to answer and tend to get down voted.

Comment: @DaveNewton Alright, thank you. Yeah, normally I would provide it.

Comment: Cool. Yup, it's hard to know where to start looking sometime. I generally wrap stuff up in a logging HOC to track down fairly arbitrary stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

After some divide-and-conquer debugging, I found the culprit:

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stuff }}></p>
```

Changing it to this fixes the issue:

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stuff }} />
```

Comment: How come another `{` is not required to match up with the `}}`?